# Has anyone attempted to rewrite the bitcoin software and protocol?

Tags: protocol

As anyone who has looked at the bitcoin protocol in depth can tell, it is really a huge mess of different encodings, hashing styles, and endian conversions. Although it would be a fairly cosmetic change, are there any projects out there to attempt to rewrite bitcoin and it's protocols to be more consistent and easier to maintain for the developers? (yes, I know it would have to be it's own coin or whatever)

Comment: I have voted to reopen this question because it's specifically asking about a *different* coin protocol, incompatible with Bitcoin.

Comment: Mh, I might have misread that. It seemed to ask for a rewrite of Bitcoin, more readable and cosmetic changes only, i.e. an alternative Implementation. I read the last sentence as an assumption that it might be another Coin. Perhaps @Earlz could clarify?

Comment: @Murch no I meant not just a new implementation, but a new protocol as well. Notice the **and it's protocols* in the question. It would be something with only the ideas of bitcoin, but where the protocols and technical details would be completely incompatible

Comment: Reopened, @GregHewgill thank you for noticing.

Comment: Isn't this the very definition of an altcoin?

Comment: @NateEldredge no it's not. Every altcoin I know of is basically just a fork of bitcoin with some changes to the parameters. They all use the same general protocol and such

Answer (score 1):

I believe that is what the [NXT](http://wiki.nxtcrypto.org/wiki/Nxt_Wiki) project is attempting to do.

It is a from scratch implementation of the ideas introduced by Bitcoin et al. They use Proof-of-Stake and claim to provide "built-in support for robust features such as a decentralized peer-to-peer exchange, voting system, messaging/chat, decentralized DNS, and options for instant transactions".